# Check if IPhone is Syncing a Contact Group with Outlook

Tags: iphone, ios, outlook, contacts, synchronization

Is there a way to programmatically check the accounts an IPhone is syncing with? 
I want to check if the user is syncing contacts with outlook, and if so which group of contacts.

If the user is already using outlook to sync contacts than the app will simply let outlook do all the hardwork (the data source is the same).  Otherwise the app will add the contacts to the phonebook and manage keeping them in step when the app is running.

1. So is it possible to check existing sync configurations?
2. Whats my best approach here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, there is no APi you can call to check if the device is syncing.
2. Do the hard work your self, since there is no way to tell if the device is being synced.